# Could not leave sessions, local media has already been stopped in Safari - IceLink 3

Tags: javascript, webrtc, icelink

I am using IceLink 3 (V3.11- Web) SDK for video meetings and I want to record the meeting in the local system. I have one issue for specific in Safari. When we try to upload recorded videos at that time below issue occurred. In other browsers it's working well, but does not work in Safari.

[image: Click here to see the images]